# Python не хочет открывать сайт!

Tags: python, webbrowser

```
  from  gtts import  gTTS
  import  random
  import time
  import playsound
  import speech_recognition as sr
  import webbrowser
  import wikipedia
  import datetime


  def listen_command():
     r = sr.Recognizer()
     with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Скажите вашу каманду!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

     try:
         our_spec = r.recognize_google(audio, language='ru')
         print('Вы сказали: '+our_spec)
         return our_spec
     
     except sr.UnknownValueError:
        return 'ошибка'
     except sr.RequestError as e:
        return 'ошибка'


   def do_this_command(message):
         message = message.lower()
      if 'привет' in message:
         say_message('привет друг')
      elif 'пока' in message:
         say_message('Аливедерчи')
         exit()
      elif 'открой YouTube' in message:
         webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

      elif 'открой Google' in message:
         webbrowser.open('google.com')

      elif 'время' in message:
         strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")    
         say_message(f"Император, время {strTime}")
      else:
         say_message('Каманда не распознана')


  def say_message(message):
      voice = gTTS(message, lang='ru')
      file_voce_name = "_audio_"+str(time.time())+'_'+str(random.randint(0,100000))+'.mp3'
      voice.save(file_voce_name)
      playsound.playsound(file_voce_name)
      print('Голосовой ассистент: '+message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
       command = listen_command()
       do_this_command(command)
```

Comment: Команды выполняет корректно слышит их и выводит правильно но не хочет открывать имено с брайзером , время нормально показывает

Comment: Дайте больше подробностей, что бы мы могли вам помочь, опишите что ожидаете и что получаете, более конкретно, пожалуйста. Пока что не ясно, что именно у вас идёт не так. Снизу вопроса есть кнопка "править"

Comment: Нет адреса ``youtube.com``, а есть ``https://youtube.com``. Также непонятно, почему ты думаешь, что команда "открой YouTube" распознаётся правильно и именно так.

Comment: В терминале выводится правильно название

Comment: То есть так и пишет "открой Google" (с заглавной буквы), а не "открой гугл", например?

Comment: Да точно так и выводится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этой строкой команды приводятся в **нижний регистр**:

```
message = message.lower()
```

а ниже происходит поиск подстроки с символами в **верхнем регистре**

```
elif 'открой YouTube' in message:
```

чего никогда не удастся сделать.

Как вариант, приведи во всех elif строки в нижний регистр.